# Adding Values in Html

Tags: html

I am creating an `HTML` Invoice. The system we use outputs the data to html in `HTML`. I put the relevant tag (such as `{{order_purchasedate}}`) and the values are displayed there instead.

I need the invoice to display the total order weight for all items in the order. The weights will be displayed as numbers in a list for example "60 80 120" with just a space separating them.

How can I add the numbers is `html` and only display the total?

I know I could use Java but I am not familiar with this. If someone could help that would be great.

Ben

*edit I have made an attempt at the code. I am struggling getting the output. I am sure you guys must think me an idiot!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Invoice</h1>

<p id="order_weight"></p>

<script>
getTotal = function(values){

    var total = values.split(" ").reduce(function(a,b){

        a = parseInt(a)
        b = parseInt(b)

        return a+b   

    });

    return total
}   
document.getElementById("order_weight").innerHTML = getTotal(a+b);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a code example? The thing you want to achieve cannot be done with HTML, so a bit of code may be helpful as javascript or php could help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to take your values and calculate total value.

```
getTotal = function(values){

    var total = values.split(" ").reduce(function(a,b){

        a = parseInt(a)
        b = parseInt(b)

        return a+b   

    });

    return total
}
```

and then just call that function

```
getTotal(x)
```

where x is your list

Here is the working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/o89f1mj5/1/

Comment: Thank for being so helpful. I am still learning all this, there is such a knowledge base here. How would I incorporate in my html code?

Comment: You welcome. Need to see your code to be able to help you with the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>

<h1>Invoice</h1>

<p id="order_weight"></p>
    <input id="total" name="total" type="text"></input>
    <input id="totalBtn" type="button" value="Get Total" onClick="getTotal();"></input>
</body>

<script>
    function getTotal() {
    var values = $('#total').val();
    alert(values);
    var total = values.split(" ").reduce(function(a,b){

        var a = parseInt(a);
        var b = parseInt(b);

        return a+b;

    });

    document.getElementById('order_weight').innerHTML = "Value: " + total;
}

</script>
```

Working JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o89f1mj5/9/

In the JSFiddle put "5 15 30" into the text box (without the quote of course) and it will make the paragraph be `50`

This is what @mgibala did above using a Textbox and a Button.  His answer should be accepted I am just giving you it in application with a variable input option.